# Regex - extract rest of string after specific sequence

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a long string with random letters, numbers, and spaces.

I need a regex expression to pull out the part of the string after the sequence of characters and numbers --> `AQ102`.

For example :

```
string t = "kjdsjsk158dfdd 125.196.168.210helloAQ102Lab101 section2";
```

desired output:

> Lab101 section2

Comment: Have tried the expression (\w+)$ but it doesn't work with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use

```
string s = t.Split("AQ102").Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need Regex for this. A simple split should suffice:

```
string output = input.Split(new string[] { "AQ102" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```

Depend on how sure you are of your input, you may want to check that `AQ102` exist first, or even to count how many times... but as I said, depends on your scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The string will always have AQ102 in it, however before and after this sequence will always vary. I am new to coding and still figuring out my way. Thank you again.

Comment: Also there is an error saying "Cannot convert from 'string' to 'char' with this solution.

Comment: @LK22: Sorry, my mistake, I have fixed the problem in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Or, a regular expression as originally asked for:

`Regex regEx = new Regex(@".*(AQ102.*)");`

OR

`Regex regEx = new Regex(@".*(AQ102)(.*)");`

And you can get the matches doing the following:

`Matches matches = regEx.Matches(t);`

And you can get the match by referencing the first index:

`matches[1]`

OR, if you're really confident:

`string val = regEx.Matches(t)[1].Value;`